# function to repeat same numbers y times

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that returns the number x. y number of times. The function should be able to take in multiple 2d arrays. There will be only 2 elements per input array.

So for example: function([4,3][2,2][12,5])
//output should be exactly: 444, 22, 1212121212

I have solved most of the problem but I am stuck when x is a 2 digit number.
would appreciate some help in solving this. I must return the solution as a string with a comma (' ,') that separates the different arrays. 
Here is my code as of now:

```
 function repeatnumber(data){
    var result = " "; 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            if (Array.isArray(data[i])){
                var x = data[i][0]
                var y = data[i][1]
                for(var j = 1; j <= y; j++){
                    result = result + x;
                }
            }
        }
    var number = result
    var answer = number.match(/(\d)\1*/g)
    return console.log(answer);
}

repeatnumber([[10, 2][11,1]])// DOESN'T WORK!! output must be: 1010,11
repeatnumber([[1, 2], [2, 3]]) //works
repeatnumber([[1, 4], [3, 6], [9, 2]]) //works
```

Comment: What exactly do you think `[10, 2][11,1]` will evaluate to?

Comment: [10, 2][11,1] ins not multiple 2d arrays. do you want to evaluate it as 2d array?

Comment: basically when the function runs with an input of: ([[10,2][11,1][6,4]]) it should return an output as follows: 1010 , 11, 6666

Comment: `[[10,2][11,1][6,4]]` evaluates to `[undefined]`. Nothing you do in your function is gonna change that.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if you got a nested array and map new values and join later all arrays with comma.

```js
function repeatnumber(array) {
    return (Array.isArray(array[0]) ? array : [array])
        .map(([value, length]) => Array.from({ length }, _ => value).join(''))
        .join(', ');
}

console.log(repeatnumber([42, 7]));
console.log(repeatnumber([[10, 2], [11,1]]));
console.log(repeatnumber([[1, 2], [2, 3]]));
console.log(repeatnumber([[1, 4], [3, 6], [9, 2]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using es6 this could be the simplest.

---

```
let repeatnumber = (inputArr) => {
  return inputArr.map((inp) => `${inp[0]}`.repeat(inp[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma between two arrays, make it

```
repeatnumber([[10, 2],[11,1]])
```

Also, your regex won't work properly when you are adding two digit number, change your logic as

```
function repeatnumber(data) 
{
    var answer = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        if (Array.isArray(data[i]))
        {
            var x = data[i][0]
            var y = data[i][1]
            result = "";
            for(var j = 1; j <= y; j++)
            {
                  result = result + x;
            }
            answer.push(result)
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function repeatnumber(data) {
  var answer = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(data[i])) {
      var x = data[i][0]
      var y = data[i][1]
      result = "";
      for (var j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
        result = result + x;
      }
      answer.push(result)
    }
  }

  return answer;
}
console.log(repeatnumber([
  [10, 2],
  [11, 1]
])) ;

console.log(repeatnumber([
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3]
])) ;

console.log(repeatnumber([
  [1, 4],
  [3, 6],
  [9, 2]
])) ;
```

**Edit**

Or a more concise method using `fill` and `reduce`

```
function repeatnumber(data) 
{
    return data.map( s => Array( s[1] ).fill( "" ).reduce( (a,c) => a + s[ 0 ], "" ) )
}
```

Or using `fill` and `join`

```
function repeatnumber(data) 
{
    return data.map( s => Array( s[1] + 1 ).fill( "" ).join( s[ 0 ] ) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the solution.

```
function repeatNumber(data) {
var results = '';
data.forEach(function(arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i< arr[1]; i++) results += arr[0].toString();
  results += ',';
})
return results.substring(0, results.length - 1);
}
console.log(repeatNumber([[10, 2], [11,1]]));
console.log(repeatNumber([[1, 2], [2, 3]]));
console.log(repeatNumber([[1, 4], [3, 6], [9, 2]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, regex isn't the best option. You're making the question a lot more difficult than it needs to be. You can just make an array of each of those strings and then `join` them together. Also, more descriptive variable names will go a long way for you.

```js
let data = [[10,2], [11,1]]
function repeatNumber(data) {
 let resultArray = []    
  for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let num = data[i][0]
    let times = data[i][1]
    let newString = ""
    for (let j=0; j < times; j++) {
      newString += num
    }
    resultArray.push(newString)
  }
  return resultArray.join(", ")
}

console.log(repeatNumber(data))
```

If you're ok with a code golf solution, this will accomplish the same task:

```
data.map(([num, times]) => Array(times).fill(num).join("")).join(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function repeatnumber(data) {

var result = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    if (Array.isArray(data[i]))
    {
        var x = data[i][0]
        var y = data[i][1]


        for(var j = 1; j <= y; j++)
          {

            {
              result = result + x;
            }

          }
    }
    if(i != data.length - 1)
       result += " ";
}

 var number = result
 var split = number.split(" ");
 //var answer = number.match(/(\d)\1*/g)
 return console.log(split);
}
```

repeatnumber([[10, 2][11,1]]) should be repeatnumber([[10, 2],[11,1]]);

Answer (score 0):

**ES6 Solution**

```js
const repeat = (arr) => {
  arr.map( v => {
    const str = new Array(v[1] + 1).join(v[0]);
    console.log(str); // save this in array or wherever u want.
  })
};

repeat([[1, 4], [3, 6], [9, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Small code that works,

```
// iterate > create array and join with char > join parent array with comma

function repeatnumber(data){
    if(!data || data.length < 1) return [];

  return data.map(arr => Array(arr[1] + 1).join(arr[0])).join(','); 
}
```

A better approach, thanks to [Ariz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9381809/ariz)

```
function repeatnumber(data) {
    if (!data || data.length < 1) return [];

    return data.map((arr) => `${arr[0]}`.repeat(arr[1])).join(',');
}
```

No creation of an extra array, so huge repetitions can be done with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Single pass by nested template literals and `.reduce()` working hand to hand.

```js
var a = [[10, 2], [11,1]],
    b = [[1, 2], [2, 3]],
    c = [[1, 4], [3, 6], [9, 2]],
    f = a => a.reduce((r,[v,c],i) => `${i ? `${r},`:``}${`${v}`.repeat(c)}`,``);

console.log(f(a));
console.log(f(b));
console.log(f(c));
```